# Anyone have a launchd script for running JBoss at boot on Mac OSX Lion?

Tags: jboss, osx-lion, startup, launchd

I'm using Mac OS X Lion and just installed JBoss 7.1.0.AS.  I'm having trouble getting the JBoss server to run at system startup.  I created the below file (/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/jboss.plist) ...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple$
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>Label</key>
<string>jboss</string>
<key>Disabled</key>
<false/>
<key>KeepAlive</key>
<dict>
<key>SuccessfulExit</key>
<false/>
</dict>
<key>ProgramArguments</key>
<array>
<string>sh /opt/jboss-as-7.1.0.Final/bin/standalone.sh</string>
</array>
<key>RunAtLoad</key>
<true/>
<key>UserName</key>
<string>davea</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

However, when I restart my computer, the server isn't running.  Does anyone have a working startup script for JBoss on Mac OS X Lion or can you see what's wrong with the above?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May all future generations benefit from the sacred knowledge I'm about to throw down (thanks, Barry Margolis).  The script is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple$
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>Label</key>
<string>jboss</string>
<key>Disabled</key>
<false/>
<key>KeepAlive</key>
<dict>
<key>SuccessfulExit</key>
<false/>
</dict>
<key>Program</key>
<string>/opt/jboss-as-7.1.0.Final/bin/standalone.sh</string>
<key>StandardOutPath</key>
<string>/Users/davea/out.log</string>
<key>RunAtLoad</key>
<true/>
<key>UserName</key>
<string>davea</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Make sure the script is registered with 644 perms using root:wheel owner and group.  Rock on, - Dave